# Use roboto font in Yii PDF extension

Tags: php, html, pdf, yii, roboto

I am converting a html to pdf using yii pdf extention but i don't want to use system font i wanna use roboto font in my html but can't able to use external file.

I just included this google api for roboto font `<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>` but this doesn't works.

Is there any other way to include roboto font in my html with yii pdf extension.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want to import font and want to use that fontfamily in your html page ?

Comment: yes exactly i want to do this but here i am not able to import any external file no included file is working or if i use `font-family:roboto` i am getting this error `TCPDF ERROR: Could not include font definition file: roboto`

Comment: TCPDF ERROR , means i think you are adding fort to PDF creation or what ?

Comment: fort? please elaborate..

Comment: means what you are generating pdf file with TCPDF and want to add externel fonts in it , that time you will get this type of error ?

Comment: So how it is possible?

Comment: $font = $pdf->addTTFfont("filename.ttf"); $pdf->SetFont($font,'',10);

Comment: where i have to add this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109681/discussion-between-brijal-savaliya-and-gaurav-aggarwal).